# SugarCRM Soap get_entry_list

Tags: magento, sugarcrm

What is wrong with this code:

```
$query = "email1 = '{$email}'";
    Mage::log($query);
    $account = $client->get_entry_list($session_id, 'Accounts', $query);
```

I can't figure it out why it doesnt work and gives me an error:

```
looks like we got no XML document

Trace:
#0 /var/www/empresam/app/code/local/Empresam/SugarIntegration/Helper/Methods.php(147): SoapClient->__call('get_entry_list', Array)
#1 /var/www/empresam/app/code/local/Empresam/SugarIntegration/Helper/Methods.php(147): SoapClient->get_entry_list('v12adkskr9va2pe...', 'Accounts', 'email1 = 'magag...')
#2 /var/www/empresam/app/code/local/Empresam/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php(17): Empresam_SugarIntegration_Helper_Methods->addAccount('v12adkskr9va2pe...', Object(SoapClient), Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#3 /var/www/empresam/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Empresam_Helloworld_IndexController->indexAction()
#4 /var/www/empresam/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#5 /var/www/empresam/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#6 /var/www/empresam/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#7 /var/www/empresam/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#8 /var/www/empresam/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#9 {main}
```

my bet is that the query is bad formatted, but i did the same procedure for 'Leads' and i can successfully return a Lead.

The Lead code is this one:

```
   $oldname = $oldfirstname . ' ' . $oldlastname;
$query = "account_name = '{$oldname}'";

$lead = $client->get_entry_list($session_id, 'Leads', $query);
```

The value `{$email}` is the right one, i have confirmed it printing to a log. I'm almost sure the error is on the query formatting, but as i said, it worked for the LEAD wy doesnt it work here?

I have tried to use 'account_name' in the query instead, but the result is the same. Both parameters 'account_name' and 'email1' are valid because i can successfully create Accounts, but not retrieve them!

Comment: and if there is a documentation, tell me where can i know core module names, module input, functions, etc. because i can't find it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every Module, email addresses are stored in another database. So, to get this query work, as the SugarCRM Soap method 'ommits' the part `Select * from Account Where`, when we are looking for `email1`, he doesnt find it as if it was a field of the table `Accounts`. For simplifying reasons, when we add an email to the table Accounts, Sugar doesn't care if that field belongs to another database, and he will let you, by default, introduce an email address. Howwever, when querying, we cannot do something like this:

```
$query = "email1 = '{$email}'";
```

Because the email is stored in a different table. To get what i want, i had to do:

```
public function getAccount($session_id, $client, $email){

    $query = "accounts.id in ( select bean_id from email_addr_bean_rel inner join email_addresses where email_addr_bean_rel.email_address_id = email_addresses.id and email_addr_bean_rel.deleted = 0 and email_addresses.deleted = 0 and bean_module = 'Accounts' and email_addresses.email_address = '{$email}' )";

    $acc = $client->get_entry_list($session_id, 'Accounts', $query);
    return $acc;   
}
```

In the query, simply replace `Accounts` by your module name, and it will work for all other modules.